# Is it possible to share variables between knitr chunks using engine="bash"?

Tags: knitr

Something like this, but it doesn't work:

````
```{r examples, engine="bash"}
    export EXAMPLES="example/path"
```

```{r example1, engine="bash"}
    echo $EXAMPLES
```
````

This works, however:

````
```{r examples2, engine="bash"}
    export EXAMPLES="example/path"
    echo $EXAMPLES
```
````

Comment: You want want to file a bug report: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues

Comment: Just FYI, this is possible with the runr package now: https://github.com/yihui/runr but I still need to polish it up before I integrate it into knitr (example http://rpubs.com/yihui/bash-knitr)

Answer (score 4):

That is a great question! It is also something I really want to accomplish but do not know how to do it (I appreciate if anybody can help me). It is not only useful for `bash`, but also for all other engines in `knitr` like `python`, `ruby` and so on. The reason that it does not work at the moment is `knitr` just runs the code via `system('engine -arg code')`, i.e. for each code chunk, a new engine session is opened, so all chunks are essentially executed in different processes.

Ideally I want an engine that opens a session and keeps on listening to new code, but I'm not sure if that is possible at all. AFAIK, the only way to share variables is to write them into files, which is obviously awkward.

Comment: @nachocab R code is handled very differently: all R code chunks share the same R session, so variables can be shared across chunks

Comment: As an alternative, would it be possible to populate bash variables using R code? That way I could set an initial R chunk with all the variables that I want to use and call them from the engine="bash" chunks.

Comment: @nachocab yes, `Sys.setenv()` is your friend: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/061-bash-variable.md ([source](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/061-bash-variable.Rmd))

Comment: and would it be possible to do: `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @nachocab Yes, you can write that in a bash chunk, but I think when bash starts up, `~/.bashrc` should be automatically sourced.

Comment: hmm, it works when I call source from a chunk, but that means I need to source ~/.bashrc in every chunk.

Comment: That is weird. I was wrong; when we invoke bash in R by `system('bash -c code')`, bash does not seem to export variables defined in `~/.bashrc`. That is beyond my current knowledge...