# How to use Login Module with Flexdashboards?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard, shinyauthr

I have a `r-flexdashboard` with `shiny` elements. This works fine.

Now I have to implement a login-page to start the dashboard.

With the package `shinymanager` I was able to integrate a login window. Thanks to the update of this post: [Modifying shinyauthr for a flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545721/modifying-shinyauthr-for-a-flexdashboard)

My idea is to show the (Flex-)Dashboard elements after a correct login. I'm able to read out, weather the login was correct or not. This is a reactive value (`TRUE`/ `FALSE`).

**My question/ problem to solve is:**

Is it possible to use this reactive value in `r chunks`, namely the `eval` option?

You can find a fully reproducible example here on github:
[FlexDB-login](https://github.com/StatistikVolker/FlexDB_login)

To login corectly use:

- user:= shiny
- password := vh

For the *fast runners* I document here the code of the main-Rmd-file:

````
--
title: "Log-In Flexdashboard"
author: 
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: inst/assets/styles-auth.css
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
if(!require(shinymanager)){
  install.packages('shinymanager', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(shinymanager)
}
if(!require(shiny)){
  install.packages('shiny', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(shiny)
}
if(!require(tidyverse)){
  install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(tidyverse)
}
if(!require(lubridate)){
  install.packages('lubridate', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(lubridate)
}

# define some credentials (you can also use sqlite database)
credentials <- data.frame(
 user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"),
 password = c("vh", "12345"),
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

```{r}

auth_ui(id = "auth")

# Q1: How to transform to 'moduleServer'?
auth <- callModule(
   module = auth_server,
   id = "auth" ,
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials) # data.frame
   # check_credentials = check_credentials("path/to/credentials.sqlite", passphrase = "supersecret") # sqlite
)


```

```{r}
# Store result of authentification in a reactive variable 
eval_login <- reactive({
     auth$result
     })

# Some Checks (printed in the Dashboard!)
# FALSE if not looged in or login failiure
# TRUE if correct login used
reactive(auth$result)
eval_login

# isolate() the reactive variable is always FALSE
isolate(eval_login())

```



<!-- does not work: 'isolate(eval_login())' alsway FALSE -->
```{r, child="Child_test.Rmd", eval = isolate(eval_login())}
```

<!-- does not work: 
Error in : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
* You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer. -->
<!-- ```{r, child="Child_test.Rmd", eval = eval_login()}
``` -->

<!-- does not work: 
Error:  ungültiger Argumenttyp -->
<!-- ```{r, child="Child_test.Rmd", eval = reactive(auth$result)}
``` -->
````

This solution is unfortunately down: [Add authentification on a Flexdashboard Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076258/add-authentification-on-a-flexdashboard-rmarkdown)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Below please find the closest to a solution I was able to come up with. I'm not sure why the child document isn't rendered properly - maybe you can built up on this:

````
---
title: "Log-In Flexdashboard"
author: 
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: inst/assets/styles-auth.css
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
if(!require(shinymanager)){
  install.packages('shinymanager', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(shinymanager)
}
if(!require(shiny)){
  install.packages('shiny', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(shiny)
}
if(!require(tidyverse)){
  install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(tidyverse)
}
if(!require(lubridate)){
  install.packages('lubridate', dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  library(lubridate)
}

# define some credentials (you can also use sqlite database)
credentials <- data.frame(
 user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"),
 password = c("vh", "12345"),
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

```{r}
auth_ui(id = "auth")
# Q1: How to transform to 'moduleServer'?
auth <- callModule(
   module = auth_server,
   id = "auth" ,
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials) # data.frame
   # check_credentials = check_credentials("path/to/credentials.sqlite", passphrase = "supersecret") # sqlite
)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
# https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#chunk-options
# https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327258/is-it-possible-to-share-variables-between-knitr-chunks-using-engine-bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827788/knitr-child-throws-error-after-upgrade-to-r-3-0

res <- knitr::knit_child(input= 'Child_test.Rmd', quiet = TRUE)
reactive({
  if (auth$result) {
    cat(res, sep = '\n')
  }
})
```
````

Comment: 2. Sorry for the delay in answering. At the one hand I was very busy at the other hand I tried a lot to eval the `cat(res, sep = '\n')` - unfortunately without any success until now.

Comment: It's rendering fine once you put it outside the `reactive` call. However, currently I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Main problem in my understanding is, that `class(cat(res, sep = '\n'))` is `NULL`. So there is no possiblity to transform the object to an object that is evaluable.

Comment: I added my tries into the code and pushed it on github. Maybe this gives some ideas for a solution. :-)